# Angular resource with integer parameter builds wrong url

Tags: angularjs, http, restful-url, angular-resource, query-string

I am trying to use the following code to communicate with a RESTFul service:

```
$scope.makeRequest = function(){
    params = {};
    params['3'] = 'X';
    params['length'] = 5;

    var resource = $resource('/foo', {});
    var result = resource.query(params, function(){
       console.log(result);
    });
}
```

This request works, and calls the expected url: http://localhost:3000/foo?3=X&length=5

However, when the integer field is the value of the 'length' field minus one:

```
$scope.makeRequest = function(){
    params = {};
    params['4'] = 'X';
    params['length'] = 5;

    var resource = $resource('/foo', {});
    var result = resource.query(params, function(){
       console.log(result);
    });
}
```

This snippet ignores the 'length' field, and makes a request to: http://localhost:3000/foo?4=X

My questions are:

1. Where does this behaviour come from?
2. Is there a better way to make this request? Can I avoid multiple integer parameters, considering that I would need more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to just set up an literal object like this:

```
params = {'4':'X', 'length': '5'}
```

Comment: This has the same outcome. The params object is created correctly, the problem is with how the resource makes the request.   And I couldn't have used this anyway, because I wanted to create the params object dinamically.

Comment: Oh I see, but just one thought, what is the point to build params object with number values instead of a string representing that number? That make any sense to you?

Comment: Actually, that was the problem, If the value for 'length' is of string type, it works. Thanks, I still have no idea about why this happens, though.